# Importing code and running from terminal problem

Tags: python, terminal

I am relatively new to Python and I am having some Python code which is organised under separate subfolders, each of which has a **init**.py file. However, when I run the code, I have two issues (see image example with link at the end of the text):

1. When I attempt to import code (called data_utils) under e.g. subfolder "utils" from a code (called  base_loader) which is under subfolder "loaders", none of the sobfolders and codes is recognised. I have followed similar topics in the community, and double checked that all subfolders contain **init**.py files, but still can't figure out what's going wrong.
2. When I attempt to run an experiment calling (all the interconnected codes) using the "python3 experiment.py" code from the terminal, I get an invalid syntax error which I really don't understand why! I double checked my spelling and whether the code is listed under the path, but nothing works.

Any ideas would be so much appreciated as I am stuck!

[See Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzyfz.png)

Comment: try -" import ..utils.data_utils ". Basically dot notation to move up a level from your current code file and then try the import

Comment: Thank you Anshul, I tried that but it did not work. It's very odd!. I suspect/hope that it is some straightforward fix.